# Firefox supports video through <img> tag. How does it work?

Tags: firefox, video-streaming

I installed the "[IP webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=nl)" app on my phone and it opens a videofeed via HTTP to a browser. I can then just put this code:

```
<img src="http://192.168.3.105:8080/video">
```

in a page, and it streams. Using this code:

```
<video width="400" height="200" controls>
        <source src="http://192.168.3.105:8080/video" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```

it doesn't work. How can an `<img>` tag stream video, and a `<video>` tag fail to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for camera feeds to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG as the format.  It looks like a sequence of JPEG images from the point of view of the browser.  `<img>` knows how to deal with JPEG images (in fact it treats it the same way as it would treat the src being changed every so often), but `<video>` doesn't know how to deal with this particular video format.